# How to prevent programs from making new entries in task scheduler when installing them on windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, firewall, scheduled-tasks

how can you prevent programs from making new entries in task scheduler or new startup entries when you install them like flash or acrobat reader?
I want to block this or better: they should ask for my permission.

I am on my Desktop PC with win7 and i am the admin. But i dont always want to check if programs do new entries when installing or updating them.

i hope you understand what i mean ;)

cheers
john

Answer (score 1):

#### Prevent Applications from Creating Startup Entries and Scheduled Tasks

Prevent apps from creating startup entries as follows:

1. Deny your user account the **Create files / write data** NTFS permission to the following folders:

   - %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
   - %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
   - %SystemRoot%\Tasks
2. Deny your user account the **Set Value** Registry permission to the following locations:

   - HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
   - HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
   - HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run (64-bit OS only)
   - HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run (64-bit OS only)

This covers some of the more common startup locations in the file system and the Registry.  However, for a truly comprehensive lockdown, you'd need to do this to all of the Startup locations.  And there's [lots of them](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/04/windows-automatic-startup-locations/).

If you use a different account than your own to install or update software, deny the above permissions to whatever account will be used.

You *may* also have to set these permissions for the SYSTEM account, as some programs will run their installation routines in that account's context instead of the account that started the installation.  It's also possible *other* user identities may be used, in which case you'd need to deny permissions to those accounts as well.  **If you run into either of these cases, you may wish to ask yourself if fiddling with these permissions is worthwhile versus simply reviewing startup entries after program installation.**

---

> How can you prevent programs from making new entries in task scheduler or new startup entries....or better: they should ask for my permission.

Blocking creation of startup entries is one thing. Configuring Windows to ask you before allowing an application to perform one or two of tens out of thousands of operations executed during software installation or update is another story.  If you really want to get this granular, some security programs can be configured to monitor Windows' Startup locations and notify you when a program modifies them.

Personally after installing a program I prefer to review changes made to my startup entries using Microsoft's [AutoRuns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) utility. As for updating programs, I find it rare that new Startup entries get created. The one exception is that programs will re-create startup entries I've disabled if they were part of the original installation.